Always get newest nuget package, when having a "*" reference
We have several internal nuget packages. We always want to reference the newest (none preview) version of these pakcages. So we set reference like this:
<PackageReference Include="..." Version="*" />

This works fine in our CI setup. It always uses the newest package.
But visual studio is stuck on the initial package. If you go to update it can see there is a update. And I can update the package. But this will remove the wildcard version reference and lock the version to the upgraded.
Is there anyway to "force" Visual Studio to just grab the newest version.
Nuget clear didn't seem to fix the problem.
Ticked off both options in "Package Restore" in options. Didn't help either

Nuget supports Floating versions.I did a quick test with Newtonsoft.Json in VS2022(17.11.5) and it produces the following package reference.<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="*" />.This gave me the latest version of Newtonsoft.Json. Could you provide a repro of this?

It will give you current latest version. But once a new package is released, visual studio will continue to reference the old, initial "latest" package.
So what version you get, depends on the initial restore time. As far as I can tell.
I would like Visual Studio to restore from sources, if there is a newer version.

Did you check if you disable Allow Nuget to download missing packages from Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > General?


I would like Visual Studio to restore from sources, if there is a newer version.

Visual studio supports automatically restore packages when a newer version is available. Please check if you disable NuGet to download missing packages from  Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > General.

Please  tick the option, then it will download the missing(the newer version) package.
FYR Allow NuGet to download missing packages
